# How to find previous row using Week Number and Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that has week number and year as two columns. Week number could be from 0 to 52 for each year, now problem is I have to find out previous update as week number and year on the basis of current update value, for example if current update is week-17 year-2018 then find previous update. It could be 2017 year's week 52 or 2018 years week 15. What could be the query to do just that.

I have tried this :

```
SELECT TOP(1) WEEKNUM AS WEEK,YEARNUM AS YEAR 
FROM UPDATE_TABLE
WHERE (WEEKNUM < 22 and YEARNUM = 2019) or (YEARNUM < 2019 ) 
ORDER BY WEEKNUM DESC,YEARNUM DESC
```

but it fails at OR part as only year less than 2018 are selected.

Here is table

`┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ weeknum │ yearnum │
├─────────┼─────────┤
│ 28      │ 2018    │
│ 19      │ 2018    │
│ 17      │ 2018    │
│ 21      │ 2018    │
│ 21      │ 2017    │
│ 30      │ 2017    │
│ 31      │ 2017    │
│ 48      │ 2017    │
│ 49      │ 2017    │
│ 50      │ 2017    │
│ 51      │ 2017    │
│ 22      │ 2019    │
└─────────┴─────────┘`

Above query returns me this result

`WEEK YEAR
 51   2017`

What I am expecting is

`WEEK YEAR
 28   2018`

which is a last update in the system. Similarly if I consider 17 2018 as current update I should get 51 2017 as output.

Hint: Week number could be less than or greater than current update week and year could be current year or any year before current update year.

Comment: This is obviously an assignment, not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Show sample data and the result your query produces, then explain why you expect any different.

Comment: If you want some help we need some more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @pzkpfw I don't think there's anything wrong with asking homework questions on SO as long as it's not "Hey - Do my homework for me".

Comment: You are getting the wrong result, because 51 > 28. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You merely got your `ORDER BY` clause mixed up. Order by year first, then by week:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WEEKNUM AS WEEK, YEARNUM AS YEAR 
FROM UPDATE_TABLE
WHERE (WEEKNUM < 22 and YEARNUM = 2019) or (YEARNUM < 2019 ) 
ORDER BY YEARNUM DESC, WEEKNUM DESC;
```

This should get you the last update week before 2019W22.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Is there any other approach do achieve the same. I mean without using AND/OR. Any sub-query for example.

Comment: As Tab suggested, you can combine year and week. He suggests `WEEKNUM + (YEARNUM * 52) ` which would work. You can also use WEEKNUM + (YEARNUM * 100) for readability or use a string (`select cast(yearnum as varchar) + '-' + cast(weeknum as varchar)`). You can even add this as a computed virtual column to your table or create a view for convenient access.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` and filter by the `WEEKNUM + (YEARNUM * 52)` as a single derived column instead of trying to apply some kind of `AND/OR` logic.

You might also use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create a cardinal column so you can easily get the previous row.   Or you might look into using the `LAG()` function.